# i want hide only specific list element

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angularjs. i have created list using ng-repeat. just i want to hide the selected list element from list:

html code which i prefered:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="profile in profileMenu">
  <div class="hederMenu" ng-hide="configureDisplay" ng-click="setProfile(profile.name)">
   <a class="anchor" style="width:100%" >{{profile.name}}</a>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

here is controller code

```
$scope.profileMenu = [{
        name : "My Profile"
    }, {
        name : "Configure"
    }, {
        name : "Logout"
    }
];

$scope.profile = "";
$scope.setProfile = function (test) {
    $scope.profileSelected = test;
    if ($scope.profileSelected == "Configure") {
        $location.path("/home/configure"); // if user click configure then this element will hide
        $scope.configureDisplay = true;
    }
    if ($scope.profileSelected == "My Profile") {
        $location.path("/home/dashboard");
        $scope.configureDisplay = false;
    }
    if ($scope.profileSelected == "Logout") {
        window.location.assign("http://mitesh.demoilab.pune/")
    }
    return $scope.profileSelected = test;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having ?

Comment: clicking on list element all list elements are hide now

Comment: just i want to hide specific list element hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the configureDisplay property on the actual "Configure" profile item. Not sure what you're doing with the selection list, but I assume you would want the "Configure" item visible again when selecting another item. Therefore you'll also have to reset the "Configure" item back to false when selecting another item.

I modified your example a bit. Notice instead of passing the profile.name on setProfile, i'm passing the profile object. This just simplifies the interaction.

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="profile in profileMenu">
  <div class="hederMenu" ng-hide="profile.configureDisplay" ng-click="setProfile(profile)">
   <a class="anchor" style="width:100%" >{{profile.name}}</a>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>

$scope.setProfile = function (selectedProfile) {    
    //reset the items
    for (var i in $scope.profileMenu) {
        $scope.profileMenu[i].configureDisplay = false;
    }

    if (selectedProfile.name == "Configure") {
        $location.path("/home/configure"); // if user click configure then this element will hide
        selectedProfile.configureDisplay = true;
    }
    if (selectedProfile.name == "My Profile") {
        $location.path("/home/dashboard");
    }
    if (selectedProfile.name == "Logout") {
        window.location.assign("http://mitesh.demoilab.pune/")
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: YEs you right i just want to reset back configure. here is the answer just what i want ...thanks..@ reinard

Answer (score 0):

you need to do few changes ,

```
 <li ng-repeat="profile in profileMenu">
  <div class="hederMenu" ng-hide="profile.configureDisplay" ng-click="setProfile(profile)">
   <a class="anchor" style="width:100%" >{{profile.name}}</a>
  </div>
 </li>
```

And in controler,

```
$scope.setProfile = function (test) {
    $scope.profileSelected = test.name;
    if ($scope.profileSelected == "Configure") {
        $location.path("/home/configure");
        test.configureDisplay = true;

    }
    if ($scope.profileSelected == "My Profile") {
        $location.path("/home/dashboard");
        test.configureDisplay = false;

    }
    if ($scope.profileSelected == "Logout") {
        window.location.assign("http://mitesh.demoilab.pune/")
    }
    return  test;
}
```